# Angular Directive Transclusion within ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with transclusion within ng-repeat directive. Angular does not find .transclude element within template so replacement does not happen. I believe this is caused by the fact that ng-repeat removes the .transclude by the time of transclusion. I would like to know how to replace before ng-repeat get his hands on the placeholder or how to solve this problem in any other way.

*Sidenote: If I use ng-transclude directive instead, then the code is
working as expected, but then I have to use $parent
{{$parent.item.name}} to access values, which I do not like.*

Here is the minified version of my code:

**html**

```
<div mydir="items">
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

**template.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="transclude"></div>
</div>
```

**directive**

```
app.directive("mydir" , function(){
    return {
        templateUrl : "template.html",
        transclude : true,
        scope : {
            items: "=mydir"
        },
        link : function($scope , $element , attrs , $ctrl , $transclude){
            $transclude(function($content){
                $element.find(".transclude").replaceWith($content);
            });
        },
    };
})
```

**expected result before compile**

```
<div mydir="items">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add some more context, what you are trying to achieve exactly? That would help to point you towards other-solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option that I think will get you where you are going.  Basically, it grabs the contents of your html directive `{{ item.name }}` and builds a dynamic template within the compile function of the directive.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive("mydir" , ['$compile', '$templateRequest', function($compile, $templateRequest){
    return {
        scope : {
            items: "=mydir"
        },
        compile: function($element) {
          var transclude = $element.html();
          $element.html('');
          return function(scope, elem) {
              $templateRequest("template.html").then(function(html){
                  var tpl = angular.element(html);
                  tpl.children('.transclude').append(transclude);
                  $compile(tpl)(scope);
                  elem.append(tpl);
              });
          };
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name: "Item 1"
  },{
    name: "Item 2"
  }]
});
```

Here is the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/AEvDHjkW6S4mwwHi5RBS?p=preview).

Comment: I saw these kinds of solutions across the web but the fact that I load the template instead of assigning to a variable made it a no-go for me.

Comment: Use `$templateRequest` to load it from a file.  Plunker is updated.